# PowerBI Power Query Oracle Join tables

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerquery

I have Googled for a long time, but guessing that I struggle to find the right way to ask Google for my questions. I guess my question is pretty easy to solve, just as I need to know how ;)

I just started using PowerBI, and have established a connection to a Oracle database.

My challenge is:

I need to create some kind of "join" towards multiple tables, so I get the data I need.

Example:

```
Table 1
Table1_Id
Table1_FirstName

Table 2
Table2_Id
Table2_Table1_Id
Table2_LastName

Table 3
Table3_Id
Table3_Table2_Id
Table3_Email
```

etc....

And the user might have 100 emails, so there could be multiple rows here.

--

How do I do this? I've tried with "merge"/join I think, but maybe in the wrong way, as I get sh*t load of rows in return, more than I should.

I hope I'm clear, if not, please let me know and I will try to be more clear

Brgds
Kristian

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PowerBi, but - from what you said - it looks like you didn't properly join all tables and there's - somewhere - *cross join* which results in too many rows to be returned.

If you'd write query yourself (I presume PowerBI lets you do that in a GUI), it would be something like this:

```
select a.first_name,
       b.last_name,
       c.email
from table1 a join table2 b on b.table1_id = a.table1_id  --> this
              join table3 c on c.table2_id = b.table2_id  --> this
```

I marked joins you should be having.